# Node js, Wait, until get all data from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have a problem with async function and callbacks in Node js. I need to get my friends' all posts and display it. But if i do that without setTimeout(), it returns only some part of data. How can i solve this problem without putting setTimeout? Of course it's absurd to wait for 5-6 or 10 seconds to get all data. I also tried with Promises, but again response is incomplete. Please someone can help me?

```
//Sending request with axios to Controller
axios.post(packages.proxy+'users/getFriendsPosts',{id: user_id},config)
    .then(res => {
        // Code for displaying result
    })


//User Controller
router.post("/getFriendsPosts", getFriendsPosts);


//Send request body to userService.js
function getFriendsPosts(req, res, next) {
    userService.getFriendsPosts(req.body, function(posts, user){
        res.json({posts,user});
    })
        .catch(err => next(err));
}


//userService.js
module.exports = {
    getFriendsPosts,
};


async function getFriendsPosts(user,callback){
    var arr = [];
    var array = [];
    MongoClient.connect(url, async function(errr, db) {
        if (errr) throw errr;
        var dbo = db.db("drone-x");
        //Find user
        dbo.collection("users").find({_id: ObjectId(user.id)}).toArray(async function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            result.forEach(async function(element, index) {
                if(element.friends.length != 0){
                    element.friends.forEach(async function(elem) {
                        //Find user's friends
                        dbo.collection("users").find({_id: ObjectId(elem.id)}).toArray(async function(error, res) {
                            if (error) throw error;
                            //push user's friends to arr
                            arr.push(res);
                            res.forEach(async function(elements) {
                                //Find user's friends posts
                                dbo.collection("posts").find({userId: elements._id.toString()}).toArray(async function(errors, results) {
                                    if (errors) throw errors;
                                    //push user's friends posts to array
                                    array.push(results);
                                    //callback results through setTimeout
                                    setTimeout(async function(){ await callback(array, arr); db.close(); }, 2000);

                                });
                            });

                        });
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    await callback("0");
                }
            });
        });

    });
}
```

If i don't use setTimeout function, it just returns 2-3 data, but with setTimeout, it returns all data. And if data will be raise, then i need to increase the setTimeout time. But of course it's not good idea. Someone can help me?

Comment: Promise solve your problem but this massive query take too much time. Use mongoose or aggregation to sort out litle bit of it time and speed.

Comment: @AshokPatidar I tried with Promise, but it's again returned incomplete data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use try catch in this code

```
getFriendsPosts = async (user,callback) => {
    const arr = [];
    const array = [];
    const db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    const dbo = db.db("drone-x");
    const results = await dbo.collection("users").find({_id: ObjectId(user.id)})
    const resultPromise =  _.map(results, async element => {
        const friends = _.get(element, 'friends', [])
        if(friends.length != 0) {
        const friendPromise =  _.map(friends, async friend => {
            const ress = await dbo.collection("users").find({_id: ObjectId(friend.id)})
            arr.push(ress);
            const resPromise = _.map(ress, async res => {
             const posts = await dbo.collection("posts").find({userId: res._id.toString()})
                const postPromise =  _.map(posts, post => {
                    array.push(post);
                })
              await Promise.all(postPromise)
            })
           await Promise.all(resPromise)
        })
       await Promise.all(friendPromise)
        } 
    })
   await Promise.all(resultPromise)
    return { arr , array }
}
```

I am not recommand this way it take too much time. You should use mongoose and use aggregation for long Query.

Comment: Thanks, but it's again returns incomplete data :(

Comment: Can you help me how can i do it with aggregates?

Comment: It's very long query, i don't know how to do it with mongoose or aggregates. Please can you help me?

Comment: Of curse. Can you share me data sample for what you want to achive. on https://mongoplayground.net/ with bason multi collection i will make Query for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to get all my friends all posts. 
I send user id with axios. 
First I need to find the user from MongoDB with that id.
Second i need to get that users' friends
Then I need to get users' friends' all posts. 
Then callback After getting all data.
Thanks!
Here is the User Collection https://mongoplayground.net/p/I7JOLWngZDa
And here is the Post Collection https://mongoplayground.net/p/VqaH8kph98g

Comment: Please provide sample data not schema i can create schema but can't make data you can make dumy data.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/9sRm2arNFYc like this post and comment collection sample data.

Comment: What news? Did you try it?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/fTrK95JXHVf Didn't find the relationship between post and friends as you told in question.

Comment: Hmmm, Is'nt it like MySql? For example in mysql, i would match posts.id with _id right? Here is not like that?

Comment: I'm sending logged in user's id with axios.First I get user data with that id, then get user's friends with loop, then should get all friends' all posts. Am i missing something?

Comment: If it's not good idea, what can you suggest me? How can i get my all friends' all posts?

Comment: I really don't imagine it with lookup, bcoz the join is many to many, we should find every friend's every post, how the query should be?

Comment: Okay, you added await before all Promises, it can help?

Comment: Yeayyyyy, It works now without setTimeOut, Huufffttt, i couldn't solve this issue already a few days. Thank you very very much! Now i can change my all queries to this, bcoz my all queries works with setTimeOut, but of course it's absurd! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Please remove unwanted comment from this post.

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean? What is that?